# Search for a string in a file using Ansible regex

Tags: regex, grep, ansible

I have a file which has one of more entries like seen in the grep command below:

```
grep SSLFile /tmp/httpd.conf
Output:
        SSLFile  /web/certs/mycert7.crt
```

I wish to grab the filename 2nd column from the output i.e "/web/certs/mycert7.crt" using ansible for all entries that start with SSLFile using Ansible regex.

Below is any ansible playbook:

```
- name: Find file
  lineinfile:
    path: "/tmp/httpd.conf"
    regexp: '^SSLFile .*'
    state: absent
  check_mode: yes
  changed_when: false
  register: getfiles

- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.split()[1] }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ getfiles.stdout_lines }}"
```

Unfortunately I do not get the greped string as well as got a runtime error as below:

```
TASK [Find file] ***************************************
task path: /app/test.yml:895
ok: [10.9.9.34] => {"backup": "", "changed": false, "found": 0, "msg": ""}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
task path: 
/app/test.yml:905
fatal: [10.9.9.34]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: unexpected char u'_' at 7. String: {{ getfiles.stdout_lines }}"}
```

Here is the httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        <LimitExcept GET POST>
        order deny,allow
        deny from all
        </LimitExcept>
        </Location>
        SSLCipherSuite EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:!SHA:!MD5:!RC4:!3DES
        SSLHonorCipherOrder On
        SSLFile  /tmp/certs/mycert.crt
        SSLKeyFile  /tmp/certs/mycert.key
```

I tried regex ^SSLFile and it does not even match string on https://regex101.com/

Update:
Trying regexp: '\\sSSLFile.*' got the match however unable to print due to the error below.

```
task path: /tmp/test.yml:914
ok: [10.9.9.34] => {"backup": "", "changed": false, "found": 1, "msg": "1 line(s) removed"}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
task path: /tmp/test.yml:924
fatal: [10.9.9.34]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: unexpected char u'_' at 7. String: {{ getfiles.stdout_lines }}"}
```

Can you please suggest what is the issue with my playbook and how can I get it to work ?

Comment: It seems that the underscore throw the error in `stdout_lines` I don't know ansible but may be you have to remove it.

Comment: @Toto that is not the issue / answer.

Comment: Are you sure it's a "real" underscore (ASCII `5F`) and not a similar character but outside ASCII range?

Comment: @Toto stdout also gives similar error(without the underscore). Also stdout_lines is used else where in the playbook and works alright. Please consider underscore not to be an issue.

Comment: OK, but the message point to the underscore `unexpected char u'_' at 7`

Comment: state: absent - why did you give this?

Comment: @smily the task is ran in check mode. The goal is to get the result for the match only.

Comment: @Ashar: debug your full `getfiles` var to see its structure... and I'd bet a case of champagne it does not contain any `stdout` nor `stdout_lines` parameter... The paremeter you are looking for is `found` which will have value `1` (found) or `0` (not found)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you try something like below.

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    input : "{{ lookup('template', '/tmp/httpd.conf') }}"
    target: "{{ input | regex_replace('\\sSSLFile\\s*(.*)', '\\1')}}"

  tasks:
  - debug:
     msg: "{{target }}"
```

Or you can do it just with shell as below

```
  - name: test
    shell: cat /tmp/httpd.conf | grep -v '^#'| grep SSLFile | awk '{print $2}'
    register: op
  - debug:
     msg: "{{op.stdout_lines}}"
```

Comment: Instead of vars i tried set_fact however i get unable to find /tmp/httpd.conf in expected paths error while running. Note the file is on a remote host.

Comment: Getting unexpected failure during module execution. stdout

Comment: I have updated the original post with added information please check. The regex does not even match on https://regex101.com/

Comment: But then it will also match lines that don't begin with SSLFile like for example it will match ### SSLFile which i dont want. I want SSLFile to be the starting text of a line

Comment: Try \sSSLFile \s* (.*)

Comment: I tested on regex101.com and it works. I will be able to check my ansible-playbook in 3 hour from now. By the way can you please explain why ^ fails while \s works??

Comment: There might be spaces in front of SSLFile because of which it fails. /s is used to match space.

Comment: unfortunately, neither mine nor your suggestion works. I tried regexp: '\\sSSLFile \\s (.*)' with my approach but found remains 0 i.e no matches found and for your approach i get An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was:   line 1
fatal: [10.9.9.11]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution.", "stdout": ""}

Comment: I got the match issue resolved using '\\sSSLFile.*' with my approach however unable to print the output due to this error: "FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: unexpected char u'_' at 7. String: {{ getfiles.stdout_lines }}"}"      Can you please suggest ?

Comment: I debug registered variable getfile instead of getfile.stdout_lines in verbose and although the match is found the matched string is not saved in the registered variable as evident from the debug. Looks like we need to take a different approach than the one i took. @Smily your template solution did not work either

Comment: you get error because getfiles doesnt have stdout or stdout_lines

Comment: I have updated the answer just by using shell module, if you can use that